# I want to get the pom.xml dependencies in the local jar

Tags: java, gradle

I am using Gradle and add the jar in the lib directory to dependencies as follows.

```
dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/foo.jar')
}
```

But the pom.xml dependencies inside the jar are not picked up.
What should I do?